# Get np.all() of varying length ranges within a bool array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
selected= [True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, True, True, False, False, False, True]
start_index = [0, 3, 5, 8, 10]
end_index = [3, 5, 8, 10, 12] # End index itself is not included in the defined ranges
```

and I would like to get the following result:

```
result=[False, True,True,False,False]
```

In other words, I would like to get the equivalent of this code using numpy:

```
result=[]
for idx in range(0,5):
    result.append(np.all(selected[start_index[idx]:end_index[idx]]))
```

The difficulty is that the ranges are of different lengths, so I cannot just reshape the `selected` array and use np.all() on each row.

Comment: `np.logical_and.reduceat` might be useful

Comment: Is `start_index[1:] == end_index[:-1] and end_index[-1] == len(selected)` always true? If yes, `np.logical_and.reduceat(selected, start_index)` is effective.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Mechanic Pig was exactly what I needed, posting it here as an answer for better visibility:

In my situation the different ranges were successive slices of the `selected` array, in that specific case this answer was what I was looking for:

```
np.logical_and.reduceat(selected, start_index)
```